# How to change the size of a css toggle switch without using transform: scale?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I'm designing an element for a plugin called elementor. This project is really just to help me learn the functionality of developing for wordpress.

What I'm making is a "toggle content" slider that can toggle between text or predefined html. I've used the slider according to this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

I have two headings beside the switch like this :

And I'd like to use elementors php tools to adjust the slider size in real-time with css. transform: scale() works correctly, it just doesn't move around anything else and is a very crude way of doing it. Is there any other way to scale this element that will move margins with it? I've seen another plugin doing something similar by changing "font-size". This doesn't seem to work for me.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by changing all the static values that make up the dimensions of the switch from `px` to `em`.

By using this approach, you can then use the `font-size` property to change the size of the element. This will have the desired sizing effect that also affects the document layout.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3.75em;
  height: 2.125em;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 1.625em;
  width: 1.625em;
  left: 0.25em;
  bottom: 0.25em;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1.625em);
  -ms-transform: translateX(1.625em);
  transform: translateX(1.625em);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 2.125em;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch" style="font-size: 2rem">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```